# Can we rename an output image from "packer build" command over-riding the image name given in packer.json file during run-time?

Tags: javascript, json, docker, groovy, packer

I need to rename images based on parameter files.

How can we over-ride image naming during run-time while executing packer build command over a `packer.json`? My requirement is to design an automated image building environment that accepts `packer.json` file from end-user and builds machine images and names. It following certain guidelines irrespective of the name provided by the end-user.

Comment: Enhanced grammar. Highlighted the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user supplies the `template.json` then they are in control of the naming, unless you use something like `jq` to manipulate and rewrite it. Which is probably the solution you are after.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on using **jquery** to manipulate image naming. I am a novice in this field , besides my requirement is that I shouldn't be toying with the **template.json** end user provides , but to device a method to rename machine images created from aforementioned process during run-time over-riding any image-name given by end-user without editing the **template.json** file provided.